# Do you sing a rap or say a rap?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Do rappers sing raps or say raps?

- **sing**, because raps are songs.
- **say**, because you don't really sing a rap, you say it.

Comment: I think 'sing' should be used because raps are songs. I also think 'rap' can be used as a verb too as in "Rappers rap about ...".

Comment: Neither. Rappers rap raps. The verb is *to rap*.

Comment: In spite of what 2Short writes, you neither **say** nor **sing** a rap. You don't [verb] a rap. You _rap._ (v.t.)

Comment: @DanBron Stop typing so fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are possible, but *sing* seems preferable. 
You could also say *do rap* and *perform rap*. Rappers *rap* raps too.

> [rap](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rap)
>   :  to perform rap music

Anyway, here are some search results for just *say* and *sing*.
[image]

However, when looking through instances of *say rap*, it was hard to find one that matched the meaning we seek. Many examples were in the sense of *speaking about rap*, not performing rap. For example "How do you say rap in X language?" It was easier to find *say a rap*, as in

> Say a rap, [homeboy], get the mic out your butt

in ["Pimp the Hoe"](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/toohort/pimpthehoe.html) by Too Short. Examples of *sing a rap* were much easier to find.
Google books:

1. [Sing rap](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=sing+rap#tbm=bks&q=%22sing+rap%22)
2. [Say rap](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJp8H7odbOAhUU22MKHRTQDmoQPAgD#q=%22say+rap%22&hl=en&start=0)
3. [Sing a rap](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=sing+rap#tbm=bks&q=%22sing+a+rap%22)
4. [Say a rap](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=sing+rap#tbm=bks&q=%22say+a+rap%22)

So all in all, I would say that, between *sing* and *say*, *sing* is preferable.